# Programmatically select text in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, uiwebview

I'm asking this question after 2 days of research. I've read all the related questions and answers in stackoverflow and google (including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275236/custom-uimenucontroller-uiwebview) question, which is very similar but without an answer) and still couldn't find a solution. Hopefully someone here will be able to help.

I have a UIWebView with some text loaded into it. I want to select part of the text programmatically, as if the user long-pressed on it.

I've tried executing this javascript code as a response to a click:

```
function selectEl(x,y)
{
    document.designMode = "on";
    var el = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(el);
    var sel = document.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    document.designMode = "off";
}
```

I've tried it with and without changing designMode to "off" at the end of the function.
I know this code "selects" the correct element, because if I perform this command

```
document.execCommand("BackColor", false, "#ffffcc");
```

it actually highlights the element I clicked on, but it doesn't cause a selection of the text. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: http://zaldzbugz.posterous.com/how-to-mark-or-get-the-highlighted-string-ins

Comment: so still have the problem after read this one ????

Comment: I already saw this link and it doesn't describe how to achieve what I need. Thanks anyway.

Comment: if that does not help u, so that mean your problem is something else ???

Comment: see this one http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/01/12/search-and-highlight-text-in-uiwebview/

Comment: Thanks again, but this doesn't answer my question. I already know how to highlight the text background. What I'm missing is how do I mark the text as if the user long-pressed on it. Like [this image](http://www.technobuzz.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/select-text-ipad.png)

Comment: To clarify, you are asking how to accomplish two things: Select a set of text (which you and others have solutions to); and take a long-press action via javascript. Is this correct?

Comment: Have you tried faking it by firing a `touchStart`, `gestureStart`, or `selection` event in Javascript?

Comment: I just made a few attempts, including a combination of touchdown/delay/touchup and manually changing the selection. It didn't work :(

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use this.select()?

Comment: select() only works with text input fields in html forms, no? My element is a span.

Comment: how do you confirm ""it doesnt work""? maybe selection already working, but mobile safari is not highlighting your selection only?

Comment: I wrote my question that it does actually selects my text, but it doesn't show the "markers" you usually see when a user selects text.

Comment: @EliGanem were you able to find a solution to this problem? I have just asked a similar question, not realizing yours was here. Can you please help me understand how to select text? Is it possible? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21913215/setstart-and-setend-throwing-error-when-trying-to-programmatically-select-text-i

Comment: Nope, I couldn't make this happen. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Mobile Safari. When I toggle `contentEditable` to true in `touchstart` and set it to false in `touchend` it works. If I remove those lines and refresh it *still* works. If I close Mobile Safari, clear the cache, and then re-open the document with the lines removed it stops working again.

I've updated the code below with a working version (although I removed the long-press for simplicity).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

(function() {
    var node,
        range,
        offset,
        clientX,
        clientY;

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        document.body.addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
            var selection = window.getSelection();
            selection.removeAllRanges();

            clientX = event.touches[0].clientX;
            clientY = event.touches[0].clientY;

            range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(clientX, clientY);
            node = range.startContainer;
            offset = range.startOffset;

            document.body.contentEditable = "true";
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {
            var selection = window.getSelection(),
                range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(event.touches[0].clientX, event.touches[0].clientY),
                newRange = document.createRange();

            if(clientY < event.touches[0].clientY) {
                newRange.setStart(node, offset);
                newRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
            }
            else {
                newRange.setStart(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
                newRange.setEnd(node, offset);
            }

            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(newRange);

            event.preventDefault();
        });
        document.body.addEventListener("touchend", function(event) {
            document.body.contentEditable = "false";
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
})();
</script>
<body>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tempus volutpat mauris sed porta. Phasellus euismod malesuada eleifend. Donec mattis, orci quis scelerisque mattis, turpis sem pulvinar nisi, et sagittis nunc nisi sed nulla. Pellentesque pharetra consequat neque, ultrices mattis mauris auctor id. Aenean tincidunt turpis non odio gravida semper. Praesent feugiat, lorem at lacinia tristique, orci eros tincidunt leo, at adipiscing sapien felis at tellus. Phasellus ac est nec nibh posuere euismod vel vitae neque. Vestibulum mollis adipiscing urna ut tristique. Vivamus purus tortor, venenatis id aliquam nec, elementum et lacus. Praesent elementum purus eget sapien ornare laoreet. Vestibulum ac odio enim.
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: I loaded this html to UIWebView and nothing happens when I click the text. Am I missing something?

Comment: Press and hold (dont move finger) then drag, If you first try it in Mobile Safari you can see the title - you can start dragging when it says "true".

Comment: I'm sorry, but it simply doesn't work. I tried to add an alert at the end of the 'touchmove' event listener, and even though the alert is shown, no text is selected.

Comment: The alert undoes the selection, doesnt it..? Try a console.log instead

Comment: As I said, the magnifier will screw things up. I updated the answer and added a `preventDefault` to `touchstart` for demo purposes. Try it now. Really, you don't want that preventDefault. You may also want to reduce the timeout on the timer.

Comment: @EricG The alert was only to make sure that all the lines in the method are indeed executed.

Comment: @Luke, I tried what you suggested - still no go. Let's simplify things - all I need is a javascript function that will mark the first word, no need for detection of touchstart/move/end. Just a simple code that will cause the markers to appear. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already tried setting contentEditable to true. It works, however the keyboard pops-up. Is there anyway to prevent it from showing? I'll give you the bounty anyway, because of your effort :D

Comment: This is a bit of a long shot, but try the code without `contentEditable` and set webview.keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction to `NO`. Despite the name it controls whether a script can focus on an element. It may extend to beyond just input fields.

Comment: `contentEditable` is what allowed the selection in the first place. If I remove it I can't select text again.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: Make sure you are NOT using anything like this in your css:

```
* {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
```

This prevents any text selections.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but you can see that I wrote in my question that the text is in fact selected, but I don't see the markers and the blue highlighting around it.

Answer (score -3):

I came across this:

```
hitElem.style.backgroundColor = "highlight";
hitElem.style.color = "highlighttext";
```

Or,
[THIS SITE](http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/find.htm) Has written some HORRIBLE scripting but it may help you :) It works with ranges.

Comment: I really appreciate downvotes without comments... -_- NOT.