# Text selection on hyperlink in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, selection

I have an embedded `UIWebView` in my app and I need to be able to initiate the iOS text selection UI on a hyperlink.  Is there a way to do this?

I know I can [set selection information via Javascript](http://www.bearpanther.com/2013/05/27/easy-text-selection-in-mobile-safari/), but it doesn't show up in the UI. And a long-press either does nothing or brings up a `UIActionSheet` with options to copy the text and open the link, depending on if the link has an `href` attribute set.

I also tried [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491485/programmatically-select-text-in-uiwebview), but it brings up the keyboard and doesn't actually show selection.