# setStart and setEnd throwing error when trying to programmatically select text in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, range, selection

Here is some HTML that I am working with in my UIWebView:

```
<div id = "1">
    <span style = "background-color:red">
         <a href = "10&20">
              This is a link
         </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Once the link is tapped, I want to programmatically select the link text in the UIWebView (so "This is a link" would now be highlighted with the blue iOS text selection tool). This is why I am sending some range information in the href of the a tag. This is the call I am using to try and make this programmatic selection:

```
//set content editable true
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"selectElementContentsInRange(document.getElementById('1'), 10, 20)"]];
```

And this is the javascript function:

```
function selectElementContentsInRange(el, first, second) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    alert("Makes it here");
    range.setStart(el.firstChild, first);
    alert("Doesn't make it here");
    range.setEnd(el.firstChild, second);

    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
}
```

And as you can see with the alerts, it doesn't make it past the `range.setStart()` call without throwing an error. The Safari javascript debugger is giving me this error:

```
IndexSizeError: DOM Exception 1: Index or size was negative, or greater than the allowed value.
```

I have tried so many different things, and nothing is working. I am completely at my wits end and would really appreciate some insight into how to do this. I am beginning to doubt that it is even possible to programmatically select text in UIWebView. Am I wrong? Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to set the range's boundaries in the first child node of the `<div>` element, which is either a white space-only text node if your HTML really does look like it does in the question, or the `<span>` element if there is no white space in your actual HTML. In the latter case, i.e. setting a range boundary in an element, the offset represents the number of child nodes of the element preceding the boundary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I would love to get a little more clarification though, if I may. Because I am grabbing the outer div (this is really how the HTML looks btw), it doesn't really have any text in it to put a range around. So I need to get the child span, and then the span's child anchor tag in order to make a range selection. Am I looking at this right? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Lizza: I think so, so long as all of the range is contained within that one text node inside the `<a>` element.