# dom range.setStart / setEnd

Tags: javascript, html, dom, range

I am trying to bold only the text `hel` in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yarkpakv/ but it does not seem to be working, what am I doing wrong???

```js
var range = document.createRange();
var root_node = document.getElementById("test");

range.setStart(root_node,0);
range.setEnd(root_node,3);

var newNode = document.createElement("b");

range.surroundContents(newNode);
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <p>h</p>ello    
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to visualize the DOM structure of your `<div id="test">` element. It contains three children:

1. A text node that contains only white space.
2. The `<p>` element which contains a text node that has the value `h`.
3. A text node that has the value `ello`.

So your range must start with the `<p>` element and ends in the `ello` text node, between the two `l` characters. Therefore:

```
var range = document.createRange();
var root_node = document.getElementById("test");

// Start at the `<p>` element.
range.setStart(root_node, 1); 

// End in the `ello` text node, between the two `l`s.
range.setEnd(root_node.childNodes[2], 2); 

var newNode = document.createElement("b");

range.surroundContents(newNode);
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4eocj64/).

Answer (score 0):

Got it ...

```
var range = document.createRange();
var root_node = document.getElementById("test");

range.setStart(root_node.firstChild,0);
range.setEnd(root_node.firstChild,3);

var newNode = document.createElement("b");

range.surroundContents(newNode);
```

In all of the documentation, they are referencing the "Child" ... this solves that.  In the case of your Fiddle, it will wrap the Letter "h" and the two `<p>` and `</p>` tags.  Take them out and **hel** becomes bold.

**UPDATE**:

Apparently, whitespace will cause problems ...

HTML ...

TEST

Working here ... **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/j40m8f4o/)**

Reference ... **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21913215/setstart-and-setend-throwing-error-when-trying-to-programmatically-select-text-i)**

Comment: Can't get to jsFiddle at the moment; I'll create a working copy when it comes back up.

Comment: In place ... hope it helps.

Comment: it helps, but with in the case `<p>h</p>ello`  ?