# Error when trying to use setStart and setEnd on Range: Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'setEnd' on 'Range'

Tags: javascript, range

When I try to use a range, I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'setEnd' on 'Range': The offset 2 is larger than or equal to the node's length (0).
```

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function gotMark() {
        var range = document.createRange();
        var startNode = document.getElementById("dividTeste1").firstChild;

        range.setStart(startNode, 0);
        range.setEnd(startNode, 2);

        var newNode = document.createElement("span");
        range.surroundContents(newNode);
    }
</script>
```

And page:

```
<div class="ui-block-a" id="divid" value="div1">
    <div style="background-color: black; color: white; padding: 20px;" id="divid2">
        <h2>London</h2>
        <p id="dividTeste1">London is the capital city of England. It is the most
            populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of
            over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
    </div>
        
    <div style="background-color: black; color: white; padding: 20px;" id="divid2">
        <h2>London</h2>
        <p id="dividTeste2">London is the capital city of England. It is the most
            populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of
            over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Marcar com range" onClick="gotMark()"
        id="marcarconranger12" />
```

I tried following the instructions from [dom range.setStart / setEnd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27462125/4395789) to select the start and end position.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to the error with one line:

```
function gotMark() {
    var range = document.createRange();
    var startNode = document.getElementById("dividTeste1").firstChild;

    range.setStart(startNode, 0);
    range.setEnd(startNode, 2);

    var newNode = document.createElement("span");
    newNode.className = 'highlight-yellow'; // <-- added

    range.surroundContents(newNode);
}
```

Now the selection has been spanned.

Comment: Just what I need. For multiple highlights you need reverse order, because the span will interfere. There is now a Highlight API, though browser support is not wide. https://css-tricks.com/css-custom-highlight-api-early-look/ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Highlight#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 1):

While OP's code seems to be safe and in bounds, the problem often arises when making multiple manipulations on the same node, which changes its characteristics and throws off subsequent offset computations you may have made.

For example, let's say we want to add highlighting to a paragraph on an array of start-end pairs. The naive approach is to iterate forward over the pairs and perform the insertions for each start-end range:

```js
const highlightPositions = (textEl, positions) =>
  positions.forEach(([start, end]) => {
    const range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(textEl.firstChild, start);
    range.setEnd(textEl.firstChild, end);
    const span = document.createElement("span");
    span.style.background = "#0f6";
    range.surroundContents(span);
  })
;

const positions = [[0, 3], [8, 11]];
highlightPositions(document.querySelector("p"), positions);
```

```html
<p>foo bar baz</p>
```

The fix here is to ensure the positions are sorted and non-overlapping, then iterate backwards so that when the node's content changes, the index offsets earlier in the contents won't be affected.

```js
const highlightPositions = (textEl, positions) =>
  positions.slice().reverse().forEach(([start, end]) => {
    const range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(textEl.firstChild, start);
    range.setEnd(textEl.firstChild, end);
    const span = document.createElement("span");
    span.style.background = "#0f6";
    range.surroundContents(span);
  })
;

const positions = [[0, 3], [8, 11]];
highlightPositions(document.querySelector("p"), positions);
```

```html
<p>foo bar baz</p>
```

The problem can also arise when computing offsets that span across multiple nodes; make sure the offset is local to node given as the range's first argument.

There are many other strategies for avoiding the problem, including [`Node.normalize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/normalize) to glue text children back together, building up the desired text on a new node or string and setting `.innerHTML` when it's ready, etc.

Comment: so if i have multi selections like I need to highlight 10 pieces of text. how can I do that ? as parameter positions take only 2 texts

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. Are you asking how to add more items to the parameter array? `const positions = [[0, 3], [8, 11], [14, 15], [36, 124],...];`?